# Android - dynamically update layout contents (for a "submenu" effect)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

An activity in our Android application features a spinner, the selected value of which affects which other views are to be displayed in the activity (these views are inputs for *sub-parameters* of the spinner parameter, and so are spinner value specific).

The contents of the activity (below the top-most spinner) should change dynamically upon spinner selection and is visualized with this very quick mockup:

[image]

Initially, we had the sub-parameters in their own linear layouts in the activity xml, and upon spinner selection change, hid all the irrelevant sub-parameter layouts, but this seems a fairly rotten approach, and also severely undermines the extensibility of the activity (in terms of adding new top spinner box options and sub-parameters).

We've also considered generating the layout completely in code with declarations of the types of inputs needed (with some encapsulated layout generator based on these declarations) for each parameter, but this seemed a bit of an over-complication, and we'd really prefer to define the sub-parameter layouts in xml.

How should we approach this?
Would this be an appropriate scenario for using fragments? (would using fragments involve hiding and showing them just as awfully as using the sub-parameter linear layouts?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're thinking about fragments in terms of just wrapping the xml layouts, I would say it wouldn't be an appropriate scenario. I would still use fragments with future extensibility in mind(it would help also, if you could move some functionality to the fragments). For example, I hope you're not going to use the same "spinner+sub layouts" approach in  landscape tablet where more space is available, instead a master detail template would be a better option(and fragments will be a good fit in this scenario).

Comment: We only considered fragments for encapsulating layouts: we have a specific target platform in mind at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone out there seeking a solution:

We ended up having an empty 'container' view (a linear layout) within our activity's xml, which will store the sub-menus...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/algorithm_layout_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</LinearLayout>
```

and seperate xml layout files for each of the sub-menus (eg; the empty negative sub-menu...)

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context="PACKAGE.ACTIVITY"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    
</LinearLayout>
```

installing an `onItemSelectedListener` (well actually, having our activity implement it) and upon the selected spinner item changing, adjust the displayed sub-menu by clearing the container, and adding the sub-menus corresponding layout (inflated to a view) to the container...

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

    // get the current spinner value
    String choice = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();

    // get and clear our sub-menu container
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.algorithm_layout_container);
    container.removeAllViews();

    // determine which sub-menu layout to set by the spinner option
    // (we're exploiting the strings.xml string identifier for our own identification)
    int layout;
    if (choice.equals(getString(R.string.halftone_algorithm_choice))) {
        layout = R.layout.algorithm_halftone;;
    }
    else if (choice.equals(getString(R.string.negative_algorithm_choice))) {
        layout = R.layout.algorithm_negative;
    } 
    else if (choice.equals(getString(R.string.gaussian_algorithm_choice))) {
        layout = R.layout.algorithm_gaussian;
    }
    else if (choice.equals(getString(R.string.dithering_algorithm_choice))) {
        layout = R.layout.algorithm_dithering;
    } else {
        // only reached via a dev bug: you've got an unexpected spinner value selected
        // we handle this with an alert, then switch to another (default) spinner value
    }

    // inflate the determined layout to a view, and add it to our container
    container.addView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(layout, null, false));
}
```